# Vim behaves differently when editting a file named "Changelog.txt"

Tags: filetype

I created a (new and empty) file `Changelog.txt` and Vim started with completely different settings than with any other text file (yellow font, automatic line breaking, maybe more I didn't notice).

As far as I know, nothing in my `.vimrc` should cause this, unless it is the fault of a plugin (I use `undotree` and `julia-vim`). Is this some kind of a default behavior specifically for this filename?

Comment: Run `:verbose set filetype?` to find where the filetype was set and modify there if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim use the name of the file to detect the `filetype` of the file.

If the name of the file is `ChangeLog.*` or `ChangeLog` it associate it to the `changelog` file type that has some special settings.

If you want to get rid of this behavior you could add a `changelog.vim` in your `~/vimfiles/ftdetect` folder with the following content:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead [cC]hange[lL]og.txt set ft=text
```

(See `:help ftdetect`, especially items A.1 through A.3.)

This solution assumes that you have the following line in your `vimrc`

```
filetype plugin on
```

Or that you are using the default.

You can check the value of your configuration using the `:filetype` command.

Comment: I would rather place those in `~/.vim/ftdetect/changelog.vim` (`:help ftdetect`, esp. item A.3)

Comment: @BebKnoble this is what I have proposed `~/vimfiles/ftdetect/changelog.vim` or in Linux/MacOs `~/.vim/ftdetect/changelog.vim` I never know which convention to use when the OP don't mention the OS. Any recommendation?

Comment: Oof, I think I skipped the paragraph where you already said that. My bad. I'm not aware of a good convention (I sometimes say "in your home directory on `runtimepath`, but it's wordy). I default to ~/.vim because I'm on nix-ish systems. Your wording is fine.